# Can't figure out one particular twist in the implementation of ReaderWriterLockSlim

Tags: c#, multithreading, .net-core

I'm exploring the [source code](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Threading/ReaderWriterLockSlim.cs) for a class that was mentioned(for educational purposes) but stuck in one place:

1. Each instance of a lock has a unique `_lockID` assigned.
2. There is an internal `ReaderWriterCount` helper defined to store thread specific data per lock.
3. There is a pool of records defined for a thread in the thread-static field:

```
[ThreadStatic]
private static ReaderWriterCount? t_rwc;
```

4. The `GetThreadRWCount` methods returns a first empty record from the pool or append a new one if needed. Record is updated with `_lockId` reference:

```
empty.lockID = _lockID;
return empty;
```

5. And one more utility method to check if the record is referencing the current lock:

```
private bool IsRwHashEntryChanged(ReaderWriterCount lrwc)
{
    return lrwc.lockID != _lockID;
}
```

And, finally, the logic I'm struggling to understand:

```
_spinLock.Enter(EnterSpinLockReason.EnterAnyRead);
lrwc = GetThreadRWCount(dontAllocate: false)!;

// ********* some other code ********** //
                
_spinLock.Exit();
spinCount++;
SpinWait(spinCount);
_spinLock.Enter(EnterSpinLockReason.EnterAnyRead);

// The per-thread structure may have been recycled as the lock is acquired (due to message pumping), load again.
if (IsRwHashEntryChanged(lrwc))
    lrwc = GetThreadRWCount(dontAllocate: false)!;
continue;
```

The question is why this `lrwc` re-check is needed. The fact that it's placed within the lock and re-validated after the lock is acquired again after pause signalizes that the record(its owner) could be changed in between, but that means the **same** thread must request an access to a different lock at the same. And even if that's a case(have no idea how it is possible) how the spin-lock, that is local to a current instance, can help to solve the issue. There seems to be some flow in my understanding of multithreading. I would be very grateful if you could help me figure it out.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/cbrumme/apartments-and-pumping-in-the-clr

Comment: Much clearer now, thanks!